# Can't enable MyLocation with Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, currentlocation

I tried to set-up the Google Maps API in order to show my location with "map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);" but it does not work. When I write it with permission check, my app start and nothing happend. But when I remove permission check, my app crashes and I'v got this error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

But in my AndroidManifest.xml file, permissions are registered.
[AndroidManifest.xml (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxJ6l.png)

Here's my Activity :

```
package fr.turtletv.mistergooddeal.geobench;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class TrouverBancFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trouver_banc, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton zoomOut = v.findViewById(R.id.zoomOut);
        FloatingActionButton zoomIn = v.findViewById(R.id.zoomIn);

        zoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(-1));
            }
        });

        zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(1));
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        // Here's my problem below
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        // Position des bancs
        LatLng banc1 = new LatLng(48.861092, 2.426020);
        LatLng banc2 = new LatLng(48.890093, 2.390619);

        // Options bancs
        MarkerOptions options1 = new MarkerOptions();
        options1.position(banc1).title("Banc").snippet("Banc 1");
        MarkerOptions options2 = new MarkerOptions();
        options2.position(banc2).title("Banc").snippet("Banc 2");

        // Ajout des épingles
        map.addMarker(options1);
        map.addMarker(options2);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo((float) 15.0));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(banc1));
    }
}
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I just give to my application permission to Location in the settings.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu8OX.png)